# mysql - reshuffling data returned, set field value as new column

Tags: mysql, database

How could I transform this

```
 SELECT 
    FieldA
    FieldB
    FieldC
  FROM mydata
  ORDER BY FieldA;


+------------------------------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| FieldA                                   | FieldB            | FieldC          |
+------------------------------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| 123                                      | cca               |              23 |
| 123                                      | dde               |              12 |
| 234                                      | cca               |              44 |
| 234                                      | dde               |              32 |
| 456                                      | dde               |              11 |
| 456                                      | cca               |              45 |

+------------------------------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

to this:

```
+------------------------------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| FieldA                                   | cca               | dde             |
+------------------------------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| 123                                      | 23                |              12 |
| 234                                      | 44                |              32 |
| 456                                      | 32                |              11 |
+------------------------------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: You've got to give us some clue as to how you're deriving `cca` and `dd2`.

Comment: Do you have only those two values in FieldB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    SELECT 
    FieldA AS FieldA,
    SUM(IF(FieldB='cca', FieldC, 0)) AS cca,
    SUM(IF(FieldB='dde', FieldC, 0)) AS dde
    FROM mydata
    GROUP BY FieldA
    ORDER BY FieldA;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [pivot the table from columns to rows](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78) using MySQL (keep scrolling for several examples). A solution in PHP will be quicker/easier to write but less efficient.

Comment: I only just discovered it myself. Definitely one for the bookmarks! :)